# How to set up selenium in python with chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

In this case for a brand new linux machine without anything installed on it, and it does not have a gui, so everything must be done in Terminal or python.

Answer (score 0):

First, install [selenium library](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/) then install [browser drivers](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/).